# What semantic rules in Go decide when a one-value assignment occurs vs. when a two-value assignment occurs?

Tags: dictionary, go, syntax, semantics, assignment-operator

While studying `map` from [A Tour of Go: Mutating Maps](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/22), one thing I found surprising was that we can access the value for a key in a map using either one-value assignment or two-value assignment. Example code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := map[int]int{2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
    
    // Example 1
    fmt.Println(m[2])
    
    // Example 2
    v := m[2]
    fmt.Println(v)
    
    // Example 3
    v, ok := m[2]
    fmt.Println(v, ok)
}
```

Output:

```
4
4
4 true
```

What semantic rules are involved in supporting both one-value and two-value assignments using the same syntax? Are there other such special forms in Go that support both one-value and two-value assignments in the same syntax depending on the left-hand side of the assignment operator?

Further, can I write a function `foo()` myself that can return either one-value or two-values depending on the left-hand side of the assignment operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one-or-two value assignment for map index operations is a **special form** provided as a convenience, it unfortunately cannot be done in "normal" assignments.

### Normal assignment expressions:

The spec has the following to say about tuple [assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued
> operation to a list of variables. There are two forms. In the first,
> the right hand operand is a single multi-valued expression such as a
> function call, a channel or map operation, or a type assertion. The
> number of operands on the left hand side must match the number of
> values. For instance, if f is a function returning two values,
>
> `x, y = f()`
>
> assigns the first value to x and the second to y. In the second form,
> the number of operands on the left must equal the number of
> expressions on the right, each of which must be single-valued, and the
> nth expression on the right is assigned to the nth operand on the
> left:
>
> `one, two, three = '一', '二', '三'`

This leaves no room for ambiguity about the number of values in an assignment.

### One, or two-value expressions:

There are 4 cases where both one and two values are allowed on the left side of the expression. Three of them are **special forms** of assignment expressions, the last is the `range` clause.

**Index expressions**:

[Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) are defined as being of the form `a[x]`, with the notable exception of maps:

> An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V used in an assignment
> or initialization of the **special form**
>
> ```
> v, ok = a[x]
> v, ok := a[x]
> var v, ok = a[x]
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value.

**Receive operators**:

The same happens with the [Receive Operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) which is normally of the form `x <-ch`:

> A receive expression used in an assignment or initialization of the
> **special form**
>
> ```
> x, ok = <-ch
> x, ok := <-ch
> var x, ok = <-ch
> var x, ok T = <-ch
> ```
>
> yields
> an additional untyped boolean result reporting whether the
> communication succeeded.

**Type Assertions**:

Once more the mention of **special form** in [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), normally of the form `x.(T)`:

> A type assertion used in an assignment or initialization of the
> **special form**
>
> ```
> v, ok = x.(T)
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> var v, ok T1 = x.(T)
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value.

**Range clause**:

The [for statement with range clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) has looser language associated with it because it is not a modification of the normal assignment expression:

> Function calls on the left are evaluated once per iteration. For each
> iteration, iteration values are produced as follows if the respective
> iteration variables are present:
>
> ```
> Range expression                          1st value          2nd value
>
> array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
> string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
> map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
> channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
> ```

### Uses for non-assignments:

As mentioned above, all three **special forms** are for assignments only. Attempting to use multi-value returns in other expressions (function call, return, etc...) will fail as these are not assignments and do not benefit from the **special form**.

Comment: A side note: searching for `special` in the spec is a fun way to discover new and interesting things.